# Create a menu inside a Grid that opens onClick

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to create a menu inside a Grid (see img:[Menu inside a grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNOnd.jpg)). But for the life of me I can't get the `handlers` to work inside the menu.

Edit (clarification): I want to have more space for action icons inside the grid, on every record row. So to create extra space, I want to have a menu `onClick` inside each grid row (see image), this will allow me to add unlimited actions icons to the dropdown menu.

I created the menu like this (I think this isn't right, but I don't know how else to do it):

```
ux.RGridPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    newMenu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
        id: 'mainMenu',
        style: {
            overflow: 'visible'     // For the Combo popup
        },
        items: [
            {
                text: 'I like Ext',
                checked: true       // when checked has a boolean value, it is assumed to be a CheckItem
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'sitemap_16',
                text: 'Test 2',
                tooltip: '',
                handler: function(a,b){
                    console.log(this.ownerCt); //All this stuff is not working
                    console.log(a);
                    console.log( this.parent);
                    this.parent.showSelectDialog //This is what is causing me issues, this won't work.
                }
            },
            [...]
        ]
    });
```

I'm trying to call a handler inside `RGridPanel`:

```
showSelectDialog: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {}
```

I want to use the nice methods inside the `RGridPanel` so I don't need to pass the parameters. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?!

EDIT:::
I've come somewhat farther on my own using this inside the `GridPanel`:

```
loadMenu: function(){ 
    return new Ext.menu.Menu({
        scope:this,
        id: 'mainMenu',
        style: {
            overflow: 'visible'     // For the Combo popup
        },
        items: [
            {
                iconCls: 'sitemap_16',
                text: 'Test 2',
                handler:this.showSelectImportFileDialog, //this works, but it does not pass the required params
```

And

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.newMenu = this.loadMenu();
```

And on the `cog` icon:

```
  handler: function (view, record, el, i, e) {
      view.newMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
  },
```

I now am able to call `showSelectDialog` but the default parameters (`(grid, rowIndex, colIndex)` are not working. Because I call the `showSelectDialog` from inside the menu.

Comment: What exactly you're trying to achieve? According to your image, it looks like you want to show this menu on button click. Give some more specifics. The grid panel is just a grid. Its not common adding a menu inside of it, maybe you want to make some panel, and then insert the grid and the menu inside of it. Give some more details about the goals that you are after.

Comment: Or you want to make some action on menu button click or?

Comment: Add more info, does that help?

Comment: what if you add a listener inside your items instead of handler?
listeners: {
    click: function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.ownerCt);
    }
}
Does this work?

Comment: That just gives me the items inside the menu

Comment: Please see my latest edits.

Answer (score -1):

When you show menu, you can provide some infomation like so:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e) {
    grid.newMenu.cfg = {
        grid: grid,
        rowIndex: rowIndex,
        colIndex: colIndex,
        whatever: null
    };
    grid.newMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
}
```

Then in menu handler use it:

```
handler: function(){
    var menu = this.ownerCt;
    var cfg = menu.cfg;

    console.log(cfg);
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8KJ36/2/